# Where is phpMyAdmin inside WordPress?

Tags: database, backup

Even if I've been coding (mainly Java and Python) for some years, I'm totally new with web apps and PHP. So please forgive me if this is a novice question.

I had a WordPress blog with a friend who was managing all the WordPress hosting. Now my friend has decided to go away and he sent me the blog backup:

1. All the WordPress files.
2. The dump of database in `dump.log`.

I have purchased hosting where I can restore the old blog. Looking for how to set up the blog again, I found everywhere the guideline "Restore the database from phpMyAdmin", but I don't know where can I launch phpMyAdmin from the backup I have.

Please explain to me what I have to do.

Comment: Any MySQL database management program will do. I'd prefer HeidiSQL, which runs on your own desktop, but you can use a web-based one if you want. phpMyAdmin is certainly the most common web-based one, but there are others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is software typically installed by your host and available via your hosting control panel, it is not part of WordPress.

A search on web for `[your host] phpMyAdmin` will probably tell you what you need to do.